# Exporting data from a Web API in JSON format to a given Excel Range using VBA

Tags: json, excel, api, vba, rest

I have been trying to figure out a way to populate columns in an Excel Sheet using a Web API in VBA. The data to be read is in JSON Format. I tried to implement Bruce Mcpherson's solutions, but was unable to do it properly. http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/classeslink/data-manipulation-classes/howtocdataset

I tried to understand solutions given on stack overflow, but that hasn't worked yet.

The data has to be loaded in a specific sheet in designated columns.

The data is here: http://www.vehicletrack.biz/api/xlsmaster?usr=rahul&pwd=togodeamo&type=2

Sample data:

```
{"result": [
    {"name":"??? ?????",
     "type":2,
     "latlong":"26.547745,82.431729"},
    {"name":"????",
     "type":2,
     "latlong":"20.169723,85.415944"},
    {"name":"??????",
     "type":2,
     "latlong":"20.674808,76.882579"},
    {"name":"???????",
     "type":2,
     "latlong":"20.664026,76.542137"}
]}
```

in three columns A(Name), B(Type) and C(Latlong) starting from row 4 on a sheet.

Look forward to learn from masters here.

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: I am using Excel 2007

Comment: Was able to solve the problem using this solution:

http://iluvspreadsheets.wordpress.com/

Just did some tinkering with the row and columns.

Get a lot of info here, so am thankful to the community.

Answer (score 1):

The following describes using [`JSONConverter`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to set the JSON object and parse it for the required information.

After adding in the class, you must also add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime via VBE > Tools > References.

---

If we take a moment to inspect the JSON we will see the following structure:

[image: sample of the response]

The left is the actual response and the right is the tree view.

The initial object returned is a dictionary with one key `"result"`.

Using `JSONConverter` we can directly grab this dictionary value by its key which returns a collection of dictionaries. The `"["` on the left hand side indicates the collection as with `[7689]` on the right. There are `3` items per dictionary and therefore `7689/3 = 2563` dictionaries. You could confirm this using the `.Count` property of the collection.

```
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)("result")
```

We can loop over the collection setting each item to a dictionary object variable/ or just Object for late binding.

```
For Each i In json
    Set dict = i
    'Other code
Next i
```

We can then loop over the individual dictionary keys:

For Each key2 In dict.Keys
       'Other code
   Next key2

Now, you have stated you are interested in values in the dictionaries with keys of "name", "type" and "latlong"; and that you want these to go into columns `A`, `B` and `C` respectively, starting from row `4`.

So, we looping each dictionary we can use a Select Case statement on the dictionary key to determine which column the value should be written to:

```
Select Case key2
Case "name"
    .Cells(counter, 1) = dict(key2)
Case "type"
   .Cells(counter, 2) = dict(key2)
Case "latlong"
   .Cells(counter, 3) = dict(key2)
End Select
```

After each dictionary is looped we need to add one to the `counter` variable which determines which row we write to, so we write to the next row. `counter` is started at `4` so we start writing from row 4 onwards.

---

**Example output in sheet:**

[image: Example output]

---

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim json As Object, item As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strURL = "http://www.vehicletrack.biz/api/xlsmaster?usr=rahul&pwd=togodeamo&type=2"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.send
    strJSON = http.responseText
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)("result") 'dictionary one key of "Result" which is a collection of dictionaries when accessed

    Dim i As Object, dict As Object, key2 As Variant, counter As Long
    counter = 4
    For Each i In json
        Set dict = i
        For Each key2 In dict.Keys
            With ActiveSheet
                Select Case key2
                Case "name"
                    .Cells(counter, 1) = dict(key2)
                Case "type"
                    .Cells(counter, 2) = dict(key2)
                Case "latlong"
                    .Cells(counter, 3) = dict(key2)
                End Select
            End With
        Next key2
        counter = counter + 1
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```